# How can I get message pop up at each div when user clicks a radio button?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with about 20 options and I want to display an alert text such as "updated" in the same row where the option is whenever a user clicks. So ultimately if a user clicks on a radio button on option 1 it would display next to it and then the same for option 2, 3, ...

I can get the specific div designated to display the text, but I am unsure how I could do this for an entire form. Can I target the specific "name" in the input so it knows where to output the pop up text since it reads it for the ajax call?

I am struggling to make this work

```
   $("input").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var val = $(this).val();
        if(val !=='') {
          "http://someurl.com",
           { name: val,
             data: name
           },
           function(data) {}, "json"
      )}
        $(this.name).html("Data Updated").show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="form" method="post">
<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set1" name="option1" id="option1a" value="0" checked/></div>
<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option1" id="option1b" value="0"/></div>
<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option1" id="option1c" value="0"/></div>

<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set1" name="option2" id="option2a" value="0" checked/></div>
<div class="myclass2"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option2" id="option2b" value="1"/></div>
<div class="myclass2"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option2" id="option2c" value="2"/></div>

<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set1" name="option3" id="option3a" value="0" checked/></div>
<div class="myclass2"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option3" id="option3b" value="1"/></div>
<div class="myclass1"><input type="radio" class="set2" name="option3" id="option3c" value="2"/></div>
```

Comment: ***ID should be unique*** you can use ID to refer to which input you click and do what you want but ***ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE***

Comment: `$("input".click(function() {` should give you a syntax error. Maybe you can set up a fiddle for us?

Comment: another thing when working with radio button or checkbox it is better to use change event rather than click event :)

Comment: Sorry guys, been a long day, I missed the closing parenthesis as well as the ID's. I corrected it in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  var $message = $('<span class="message">Updated</span>');

  $('input').change(function (e) {
    var $element = $(e.currentTarget);
    $element.after($message.stop(true, true).show());
    $message.fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

});

Also, just change the `change` to `click` if you really want it on click.

Comment: this is what I was looking for but when I use your code, it keeps adding an additional "updated" with each click starting with 0. So when I click the first time, it shows nothing, when I click the second time it shows "updated" when I click third time is shows "UpdatedUpdated" and the 4th time it goes to "UpdatedUpdatedUpdated" and so on.

Comment: You can move the `$message` outside the change function. I edited the snippet.